# Binary operators on binary numbers in Python

Tags: python, binary, bitwise-operators

As I noticed, on the one hand, there are bitwise operators in Python, like: `8 ^ 10` which results 2, that's fine.
 On the other hand, there are ways to convert a base 10 integer to a binary number, e.g. `bin(2)`

I wonder if I could combine this two, I mean there are no bitwise operators on strings, therefore, `bin(8) ^ bin(10)` only throws an error. I guess when using bitwise operators on integers, Python's first step is always a conversion anyways.

Actually I was thinking how I could speed up operations like `a ^ b` when both a and b are high values of integers and there are many bitwise operations on them. Conversion takes too much time so I'd like to just convert them in the first place and manipulating with bitwise operators only after.
 Maybe converting each number to bool lists could help, but I'm interested if anyone has a better idea.

Thank you very much for any good advices!

Comment: Why do you want to convert the values, when the computer itself stores them in the memory in their binary format? `bin(x)` __does not__ convert `x` from decimal to binary, it just returns a string of `0`s and `1`s to show you the _binary representation_ of `x`.

Comment: Its worth noting that `bin()` doesn't actually convert an integer to a "binary number", but rather it converts an integer to a string containing the binary representation of the number.

Comment: Try `type(bin(x))` it just return `str`. So it's string.

Comment: like I said above, I want to avoid any unnecessary conversions. Hence bitwise operators only work with (10 base) integers and bools -to my knowledge-, but are evaluated in binary, then back to 10 base integer, it seems like a bit too much. Now I'm getting an input in base 10, then evaluating bitwise operators, that's at least 2 conversions and an operation, then a few comparisons, then an output in base 10.
 Now, with extremely large numbers as an input, my code won't answer in a reasonable time.

Comment: The conversion you speak of, from base 10 input to binary is done immediately on input.  As soon as you type in 255, it's converted to 11111111 to be able to be stored in memory.  More importantly however, this is not really ever something you will need to be concerned with, ever.  I appreciate that you want to write fast code, but this kind of "optimization" is fruitless, as is all optimization until you profile and identify bottlenecks.  And I assure you, this will not be a bottleneck of your code.

Comment: @SwaMPlaC0re When you're taking an input in decimal, it immediately gets written in the memory in binary, you don't even need to think about it. Whatever operations you do on the numbers, they are done over binary numbers. When you `print` them, they're automatically converted to decimal form and shown on screen. So you only see the decimal numbers on screen during input and output, but everything goes on in binary under the hood. There's no "_unnecessary conversion_" going on there.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment anymore but @jedwards and 0605002 you were right, there are no unnecessary conversions. Thanks, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to assume that Python internally stores integers as strings of decimal digits. That is completely false. Integers, even arbitrary precision ones (`long` in 3.x), are stored as bit strings. XORing two Python integers simply performs the native XOR operation on the bits as stored in memory. It loads 2x 64 bits from memory into registers, XORs the bits as efficiently as the CPU allows, and writes the result back to memory. No conversion necessary.

To be completely honest, it does *not use* some of those 64 bits (this is used for easier overflow detection in multiplication), but it does that by just leaving those bits as zeroes all the time.

Comment: well, this is awkward, I should have thought of this.. 
(but it was my guess why my code is soooo slow. Hope is a bit**)